# Trouble converting numpy array of shape (500,500,3) to (180,180,3)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, python-imaging-library

I have an array (generated from PIL image) of shape (500,500,3) and need to convert it to (180,180,3). No matter what I try, it doesn't seem to work. Here is the code:

```
window = img[i:i+window_size_dim1, j:j+window_size_dim2]
    img = Image.fromarray(window)
    img_array = image.img_to_array(img)
    img_array.reshape((180,180,3))
```

and the error:

```
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 750000 into shape (180,180,3)
```

any ideas are much appreciated!

Comment: You're trying to shove 750000 elements into an array with only 97200 elements (Just over 1/8th the size of the original). It's not clear what you expect to happen here: Are you trying to compress the image? Delete information from the image? Something else?

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to resize an image. `numpy.reshape` deals with array dimensions, not images (necessarily). Look in PIL for an image resizing function to solve your issue.

Comment: Did you spend any time reading the documentation for `np.reshape`  or the method, https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.reshape.html#numpy.ndarray.reshape.  I know it just says "Returns an array containing the same data with a new shape." but keeping the same total number of elements is implied by that.  Get in the habit of checking the docs; it will save a lot fruitless "trying".

Comment: Just resizing the image was the best bet, thank you!